# refresh many browsers on same page if action on one browser

Tags: angularjs, refresh

I searched for how AngularJS automatically refreshes many browsers which are on the same page if a user changes data on one browser page.

My Boss opens 3 browsers, he deletes data on one browser and he want all others pages to see refreshed data! without clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Not sure about what your exact requirement but you can archive this functionality by using [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#what-is-signalr) WebSocket.